# Dropdown with union query

Tags: mysql, sql, union

I'm developing a booking system and in my booking form I have a dropdown element which is returning (still) available start time slots for a booking system.

By creating a new booking the query I have created is working fine and all available start time slots are returned correctly.

QUERY :

```
 WHERE {thistable}.id 
 IN (
     SELECT id +3 
     FROM (
           SELECT p1.book_date, t.*,   count(p1.book_date) AS nbre 
           FROM fab_booking_taken AS p1 
           CROSS JOIN fab_booking_slots AS t 
           WHERE NOT ((t.heuredepart_resa < p1.book_end AND 
                 t.heurearrivee_resa > p1.book_start)) 
                 AND DATE(p1.book_date)=DATE('{fab_booking___book_bookingdate}') 
           GROUP BY t.id) AS x 
           WHERE nbre =
           (
            SELECT count(p2.book_date) 
            FROM fab_booking_taken AS p2 
            WHERE p2.book_date = x.book_date
           )
    ) ORDER BY id ASC
```

Please see video : [booking creationg](http://www.screencast.com/t/P4RQnKM2X9PH)

The problem I have by using the same query by editing an existing booking the available start time slots are returned which is fine :

18:00
18:30
19:00
19:30

but not the already by the customer chosen (and in the database saved) time slot which is in my example 14:00.

Please see video : [Editing booking with same query](http://www.screencast.com/t/fq8JtoRabYhc)

Dropdown should be populated with the following options :

14:00
18:00
18:30
19:00
19:30

I tried to create an union query to get the already by the customer chosen start time slot and the (still) available start time slots.

QUERY :

```
 {thistable}.id 
 IN ( 
     SELECT id + 3 
     FROM ( 
           SELECT p1.book_date, t.*, count(p1.book_date) AS nbre 
           FROM fab_booking_taken AS p1 
           CROSS JOIN fab_booking_slots AS t 
           WHERE NOT ((t.heuredepart_resa < p1.book_end 
             AND t.heurearrivee_resa > p1.book_start)) 
             AND p1.book_date = DATE_FORMAT('{fab_booking___book_bookingdate}', '%Y-%m-%d') 
           GROUP BY  t.id 
          ) as foobar2 
     UNION ( 
            SELECT id + 3 
            FROM ( 
                  SELECT  p1.book_date, t.*, count(p1.book_date) AS nbre 
                  FROM fab_booking_taken AS p1 
                  CROSS JOIN fab_booking_slots AS t  
                  WHERE ( ( t.heuredepart_resa < p1.book_end 
                    AND t.heurearrivee_resa > p1.book_start ) ) 
                    AND t.id = '{fab_booking___book_starttime}' 
                    AND p1.book_date = DATE_FORMAT('{fab_booking___book_bookingdate}', '%Y-%m-%d') 
                  GROUP BY t.id 
            ) AS x 
      WHERE nbre = ( 
                    SELECT count(p2.book_date) 
                    FROM fab_booking_taken AS p2 
                    WHERE p2.book_date = x.book_date 
                   ) 
            ) 
      )
```

The already by the customer chosen start time slot is returned (14:00) but the other available returned start time slots are not correct.

Please see video : [Editing booking with union query](http://www.screencast.com/t/UiBsFMs0o4)

I'm stuck and I have no clue how I could solve this issue, so I would appreciate some help here.

Thanks

Relevant database tables

fab_booking with the booking concerned into the video

[please download the sql table](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3xs5k63b9m80tw2/fab_booking.sql?dl=0)

fab_booking_taken with the already existing bookings on 25 11 2016 id = 347

[Please download the sql table](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3w5mjyy9j96jnqu/fab_booking_taken.sql?dl=0)

id 347 is the concerned booking

fab_booking_slots table which contains all possible time slots

[Please download the sql table](https://www.dropbox.com/s/b4svqte9bvwhfkz/fab_booking_slots.sql?dl=0)

fab_heuredepart_resa table which populate the dropdown element

[Please download the sql table](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pa4un249rhee8hw/fab_heuredepart_resa.sql?dl=0)

Comment: That query is pretty complex. It sure would help if you posted some some sample data for each of the tables that are referenced in your queries.

Comment: Thank you mendosi, database tables can be downloaded.

Comment: I don't fully understand your business rules, but if a booking was from 14:00 - 17:30 and they wanted to change the time, why only offer them 14:00, 18:00, 18:30, 19:00 and 19:30? Why not also 14:30, 15:00, 15:30, 16:00, 16:30, 17:00 and 17:30?

Answer (score 0):

I have to admit that it is daunting to try to untangle that query to understand the logic behind it but I think that the following query should return the results that you need.

```
{thistable}.id IN (
    /*Finds booking slots where the booking slot does not overlap
      with any of the existing bookings on that day, 
      or where the booking slot id is the same as the current slot.*/
    SELECT t.id + 3
    FROM fab_booking_slots AS t 
    WHERE t.id = '{fab_booking___book_starttime}'
    OR NOT EXISTS (
        Select 1 
        From  fab_booking_taken AS p1
        Where Date(p1.book_date) = Date('{fab_booking___book_bookingdate}')
        And p1.book_end > t.heuredepart_resa 
        And p1.book_start < t.heurearrivee_resa
    )
)
Order By id Asc;
```

I'm pretty sure that this is logically equivalent, and once expressed in a simplified form like this it's easier to see how you can get it to also return the additional time slot.

You should have a separate query to use when populating the time slots for a new booking that doesn't have an existing time slot, in which case you can just remove the single line `t.id = '{fab_booking___book_starttime}' OR`.

Comment: Hi mendosi, 
Sorry for my late reply and thank you for having taken the time to help me. 
Indeed, your query is working partially. Not because of you, but because I forgot that I will also need to check if the duration chosen (through a dropdown) is not exceeding the time available between two bookings|two available slots.
I think it would be easier for me if I could pay|hire you to do the job if you are available of course, since I need to find a solution. Are you interested? If yes, how can I contact you in order to give you the specifications and get a quote?

Comment: @marcq No, I don't think I'd be able to do that. I don't really have the hardware or software to help in any real capacity except at work. I can just answer some SQL questions like this purely using SQLFiddle...

Comment: Thank you mendosi, I understand, I will try to find another solution. Cheers