# SQL OR NOT EXISTS doesn't work

Tags: mysql, sql, exists, predicate

I have a question concerning the following query which doesn't work :

```
{thistable}.id IN (
SELECT id
FROM fab_booking_slots AS slots 
WHERE id = '{fab_booking___book_starttime_raw}'
OR NOT EXISTS (
SELECT id +1 FROM (
    SELECT taken.book_date, slots.*, count(taken.book_date) AS nbre 
    FROM fab_booking_taken AS taken 
    CROSS JOIN fab_booking_slots AS slots 
    WHERE NOT ((slots.heuredepart_resa < taken.book_end 
               AND slots.heurearrivee_resa > taken.book_start)) 
    AND DATE(taken.book_date) = DATE('{fab_booking___book_bookingdate}') 
    GROUP BY slots.id) AS x 
WHERE nbre = (
    SELECT count(taken.book_date) 
    FROM fab_booking_taken AS taken 
    WHERE taken.book_date = x.book_date)
    )
)
Order BY id ASC
```

This query should return the value from the dropdown already existing into the database and if they are available slots, the available slots.

When I'm running the 2 SELECT independently they are working.

Would appreciate some expertise here, since I can't find the reason and I'm stuck.

This thread follows the following thread :

[STACKOVERFLOW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40797958/dropdown-with-union-query/40817706?noredirect=1#comment68900435_40817706)

Tables can be downloaded there.

Thank you in advance for your support.

Cheers,

Marc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case I think the error is in the way that you have used `WHERE NOT EXISTS`. This will return `true` if your subquery returns no rows. Normally the subquery that you use with `EXISTS` or `NOT EXISTS` would be a [correlated subquery](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/correlated-subqueries.html) which references a column from the outer select (in your case `fab_booking_slots`) so that the subquery returns a different result for each row of the outer select.

So, enough of the theory which you probably already know (let's say it's for future readers), what you did here is you didn't correlate the subquery with an outer reference. This is complicated by the fact that you have used the same table alias, `slots` in both the outer query and the subquery. I would assign different aliases to prevent confusion.

I have simplified the logic in your subquery a bit, this should still return correct results. Note that there is a trap with the times that go after midnight so we need to handle them by adding a day to those times and then the comparisons will work correctly:

```
{thistable}.id IN (
SELECT t.id
FROM fab_booking_slots AS t 
WHERE t.id = null
OR NOT EXISTS (
    Select 1 
    From  (Select book_date, 
           Convert(book_start, datetime) As book_start, 
           Case When book_end < '02:00:00' Then Date_Add(Convert(book_end, datetime), INTERVAL 1 DAY) Else Convert(book_end, datetime) End As book_end 
           From fab_booking_taken) AS p1
    Where Date(p1.book_date) = '2017-01-10'
    And Convert(p1.book_end, datetime) > Convert(t.heuredepart_resa, datetime)
    And Convert(p1.book_start, datetime) < Case When t.heurearrivee_resa < '02:00:00' Then Date_Add(Convert(t.heurearrivee_resa, datetime), INTERVAL 1 DAY) Else Convert(t.heurearrivee_resa, datetime) End
)
)
Order BY id ASC;
```

Comment: Hi Mendosi,

Thanks a lot for your reply and solution since sql is still "complicated" for me. 

The query is working fine now when a booking already exists in the fab_booking_taken for the chosen date. 

But if no booking exist then no value are returned. Query should return all the available slots from the fab_booking_slots table.

Comment: @marcq when the booking does not already exist what value is being passed for `{fab_booking___book_bookingdate}`?

Comment: the dropdown is actualised with ajax. When user change the date then dropdown is actualised. It is working fine, when I choose a date for which bookings already exists, then the available slots are shown.

Comment: Please see video http://www.screencast.com/t/Q4hIPwUf8wF which shows how it works: creating a new booking to a date which have no other bookings, creating a new booking to a date that have already existing bookings and editing an existing booking

Comment: @marcq Unfortunately I can't view that video due to firewall issues. The query in my answer seems to produce correct result for me when I run with parameters of `NULL` for `{fab_booking___book_starttime_raw}` and `'2016-11-25'` for `{fab_booking___book_bookingdate}` which is why I ask about the parameters being sent by the application.

Comment: Thanks mendosi, I check the query into PHPMYADMIN and see if she's returning the appropriate value. If yes, then it means that Ill have an issue with the custom form template or the field(s) generated with the PHP framework.

Comment: Hi mendosi, With PHPMyAdmin the same query with NULL for {fab_booking___book_starttime_raw} and '2016-11-25' or '2017-01-13' return no value... with '2017-01-09' the query is returning "18 | 19 | 20 | 21 | 22 | 23 | 24 | 25 | 26 | 27" which is correct for me.

Comment: @marcq so is the return value for the November date correct too? Or just 9 Jan 2017?

Comment: Hi mendosi no for november the query is returning no value

Comment: @marcq With the sample data you provided or with some more complete data?

Comment: I have no booking into the fab_booking_taken and into the fab_booking tables for the november date, so, but if you want I can give you all the sampe datas ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129769/discussion-between-mendosi-and-marcq).

Comment: @marcq I added the revised answer here.

Comment: Hi mendosi, I could test your query which is working in PHPMySQL, in the three cases she return all the available slots of the _slots table

Comment: {thistable}.id IN (
SELECT slots.id 
FROM fab_booking_slots AS slots 
WHERE slots.id = '{fab_booking___book_starttime_raw}' 
OR NOT EXISTS ( 
Select 1 
From (Select book_date, 
Convert(book_start, datetime) As book_start, 
Case When book_end < '02:00:00' Then Date_Add(Convert(book_end, datetime), INTERVAL 1 DAY) Else Convert(book_end, datetime) End As book_end

Comment: From fab_booking_taken) AS taken 
Where Date(taken.book_date) = '{fab_booking___book_bookingdate}' 
And Convert(taken.book_end, datetime) > Convert(slots.heuredepart_resa, datetime) 
And Convert(taken.book_start, datetime) < Case When slots.heurearrivee_resa < '02:00:00' Then Date_Add(Convert(slots.heurearrivee_resa, datetime), INTERVAL 1 DAY) Else Convert(slots.heurearrivee_resa, datetime) End 
     )
)
Order BY id ASC